# Twig (Symfony2) - replace function - replacing from variables - is it possible? (part completed code)

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm close but nothing seems to work:

```
{% set a %}abc{% endset %}

{% set b %}123{% endset %}

{{ "test_abc123_xyz"|replace({ '{{ a }}{{ b }}': '' }) }}
```

It should be obvious what I'm trying to do as I think the only part above that is wrong is this bit:

```
'{{ a }}{{ b }}'
```

...but I can't get it right (I want to use the value of a and b together and replace it).

The result of above if working would be:

```
test__xyz
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `'{{ a }}{{ b }}'`, it is nothing but a simple string to twig:

```
{{ '{{ a }}{{ b }}' }}
```

would just output:

```
{{ a }}{{ b }}
```

---

Then, if you want to use [expression as keys](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#literals) in twig, you need to put them in parentheses:

```
{% set name = 'Adrien' %}
{% set hash = {(name): 'hello', name: 'hi'} %}

{% for key, value in hash %}
    {{ key }} => {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

would output:

```
Adrien => hello
name => hi
```

---

So you fixed solution is:

```
{% set a %}abc{% endset %}
{% set b %}123{% endset %}

{{ "test_abc123_xyz"|replace({ (a ~ b): '' }) }}
```

The `~` is the [concatenation operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators) in twig.